# Is a Monios-L T5 LED Grow Light good for all life stages of flowers?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, flowers, led

There is an overwhelming amount of lights to choose from for optimal plant growth. I have purchased a [Monios-L T5 LED Grow Light](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07QCT6Q4T/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) but am uncertain if it is suitable for seedlings. I am currently trying to grow indoors:

- Pansies
- Snapdragon
- Forget-me-not
- Cosmos
- Lavatera
- Bee Balm
- Corn Salad
- Hibiscus
- Zinnia
- Geranium
- Coreopsis

Comment: Some plants also require some time in darkness.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. It is very difficult to get enough artificial light to grow plants to maturity. Most of the ad looks like advertising ( no surprise). A very important number is lumens , the amount of light, not given . A temperature spectrum ( ad - 2900 K) only applies to incandescent lights and halogen and metal halide ( as I understand it) . You want the frequency spectrum of light that it emits; green chlorophyll has two absorption peaks -( I forget the numbers ) ,not provided .SO ,the CRI number is useless because that tells how natural the light looks to the eye - not how effective it is to the chlorophyll. I think you can get more technical info on light if you search under "aquarium". But try it , to maximize lumens put the light as close as you can to the plants .